# Get items from Firebase with condition

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

How can I get items from my database (Firebase) with condition?
For example, I want to get Users with age > 18.

Now I can get all users only.

```
this.$users= db.collection('Users').valueChanges();

 this.$users.subscribe((users: UserModel[]) => {
      this.userService.latestId = users.length;
      this.userCount = users.length;
    });
```

I use Angular 10 for my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase/ Firestore is a NoSql Baas (Backend as a service). It provides its own way  of Querying items.
The `where()` method takes three parameters: a field to filter on, a comparison operation, and a value. The comparison can be `<, <=, ==, >, >=,` `array-contains`, `in`, or `array-contains-any` :-

```
this.$users= db.collection('Users', ref => ref.where("age", ">=", "18")).valueChanges();
```

You will have to change query fields according to your `UserModel[]`

More info :-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Property 'where' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<unknown>'